# Git How to update current branch to master branch

Tags: git

I'm really new to Git and I'm trying to update my branch to match the master branch since there have been changes I need to download to my branch so I'm on the current workplace. I tried doing `git pull origin master --rebase` but it says

```
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

I'm not sure exactly what to do and I don't want to accidentally remove files or wipe the whole repo.

Comment: Did you try adding the unmerged files? The error message is pretty explicit, what confuses you?

Comment: Remember that `git pull` means: *first, run `git fetch`, then run a second Git command to do something with the fetched commits*. The default second command is `git merge`. So `git pull` runs `git fetch`, then runs `git merge`. The merge operation **can stop in the middle** due to conflicts, and when it does, you cannot run another merge because there's one still going on. Probably, you ran `git pull` already, and it stopped in the middle of a merge. Then you ran `git pull` again and this time it wouldn't even *start* a merge because there's still a stopped one to finish first.

Comment: In your example above, you've used `git pull --rebase`. This changes the *second* command from `git merge` to `git rebase`. However, rebase has the same "can stop in the middle" behavior, and hence the same kind of complaint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have some uncommit changes within your projects so before rebase or merge first commit them.

"error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files. hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm ' hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit. fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict."

Is error showing that you have some uncommit changes within your project.

So in your current branch write this command;

```
git add .
git commit -m "<YOUR COMMIT MESSAGE>"
```

After that rebase with master

```
git rebase master
```

Make sure your local master branch is up to date with remote master, If it is not then  write this command

```
git checkout master
git pull origin/master
```

Now move back to your branch and write;

```
git rebase master
```